# java melody - sql stat getting none - with JNDI

Tags: java, java-melody

I'm not getting SQL query get monitored under java melody - http://javawebapp/monitoring.

Any configuration am missing in the Tomcat 7 server.xml to get SQL query and JDBC connections get tracked?

This is happening with the driver - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and java melody 1.59.0 version i have used.

```
<Resource 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
name="/jdbc/oracle/myDataSource"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="test"
url= "jdbc:oracle:oci:@test" >
```

Comment: You need to at least show us the relevant JDBC code where you configure the connection.